# Custom button with style for another target type

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I created custom control for button. My control is type of IconButton. But i defined style SuccessButton for type Button. I dont change TargetType from Button to IconButton because BaseOn is set up to Button from [mahapps](http://mahapps.com/).

**Here is my code:**

Style.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="SuccessButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroFlatButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF449D44"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#4AAA4A"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

IconButton:

```
 <Button Margin="0 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Width="12" Height="12" Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{Binding Path=Icon,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:IconButton}}}" />
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Message,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:IconButton}}}" FontSize="10" Margin="2 0 0 0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class IconButton
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty 
            = DependencyProperty.Register("Message", typeof(string), typeof(IconButton));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty
            = DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(Canvas), typeof(IconButton));

        public string Message
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(MessageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MessageProperty, value);}
        }

        public Canvas Icon
        {
            get { return (Canvas) GetValue(IconProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IconProperty, value);}
        }

        public IconButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Usage:

Style has error:

> 'Button TargetType does not match type of element IconButton'

How I solved this problem? IconButton must have style for IconButton but i have style for only Button.

Thanks for advices.

Comment: I guess your `TargetType` should be something like `TargetType="{x:Type Button}`?

Comment: @AshishSrivastava `TargetType="Button"` works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to apply a Style with a TargetType of Button to your custom IconButton the IconButton class *must* inherit from Button:

```
public partial class IconButton : System.Windows.Controls.Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("Message", typeof(string), typeof(IconButton));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(Canvas), typeof(IconButton));

    public string Message
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MessageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MessageProperty, value); }
    }

    public Canvas Icon
    {
        get { return (Canvas)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
    }

    ...
}
```

If it doesn't it is in fact no Button and you *cannot* apply a Button style to a control that isn't actually a Button.